# Backbone.js "Todos" sample - Unsure why a certain fragment of code works

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This question is about the "Todos" Backbone.js sample, which is at:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html

[The following block of code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html#section-37) is in "[The Application](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html#section-30)" section, and iterates through the `Todos` collection. My issue is that the `addOne` function is passed as a reference to the `Todos` collection, but that function has a reference to `this`, which is not the same as what `this` would refer to when the function is called by the `Todos` collection object.

```
addOne: function(todo) {
    var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
    this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
addAll: function() {
    Todos.each(this.addOne);
},
```

Why does the function execute correctly when the caller is not calling it in the context of the instantiated `AppView` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just worked it out. It occurred to me that `this` refers to the `window` object by default and seeing as jQuery registers `$` globally, the function will work even if called with no context object.

Comment: ya--you've stumbled on something that is almost "working by accident".  They probably should have had a `_(this).bind("addOne")` statement in the initialize to ensure that the `this` pointer was the view and not the window

Comment: Not exactly. Take a look at my answer, the trick is `bind`’s third argument.

Comment: i thought that at first too, but check Nathan's reply to your answer

Comment: Confirmed with a breakpoint. Got a good chuckle out of this one.  +1 for a good find!

Comment: Ahh, good catch! Sounds like it's time to [submit an bug report](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues) to Backbone.

Comment: It's not a bug - as you mentioned it's just a lucky accident that it worked at all. It's just badly written javascript which fails to keep control over funciton execution scope. The right way to write that piece of code would be `Todos.each(_.bind(this.addOne, this));`

Comment: It most certainly is a bug if it's being presented as the main instructional/tutorial sample for a popular framework. In this case the bug just happens to not produce an undesirable outcome. But that's like in school when you answer a math question and your calculations are performed incorrectly but produce the correct answer only by coincidence. The teacher will still mark you wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"If jQuery or Zepto is included on the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within the view's element."

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-dollar

Context is the same (view) for both addOne and addAll and it is achieved with the third parameter in bind calls.

```
Todos.bind('add',   this.addOne, this);
Todos.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
```

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-bind

--edit

Hmm.. then again do those binds ensure the context when addOne is ran with each?

```
addAll: function() {
  Todos.each(this.addOne);
},
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that views have a $ property, but the code was being executed in the context of the collection, which as far as I can tell does not have a $ property.

Comment: Heh, true. I just checked the example and `this` refers indeed to window when ran with each.

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers, this issue was [submitted](http://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/734) on GitHub and a [fix](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/1626fa7447818f66a142f46ccade1158d1ff6324) was applied, but it doesn't really address the issue.

I think the best way to solve this problem is have the `addAll` function bind its own `this` to the `.each` iteration, i.e.

```
addOne: function(todo) {
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},

addAll: function() {
  Todos.each(this.addOne, this); // notice the second parameter
},
```

We can do this because [Underscore.js's](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) `_.each` function has an option third (second, in our case) parameter to specify the context for the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `initialize` method:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.input    = this.$("#new-todo");

  Todos.bind('add',   this.addOne, this);
  Todos.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
  Todos.bind('all',   this.render, this);

  Todos.fetch();
}
```

That third (optional) argument to `bind` is the context with which the callback gets called. It's documented [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-bind). The implementation in Backbone is [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-16):

```
callback[0].apply(callback[1] || this, args);
```

Comment: Yes, but the line `Todos.each(this.addOne);` calls the collection's `each` function directly. How does `Todos` know to call the passed function reference with the view as the context?